# "OrderItem is not valid target type for the orderedItem property"

Tags: html-email, schema.org, google-schemas

We have been working on adding Google markups to our order confirmation emails. We have added all the necessary markup in templates, but "[Email Markup Tester](http://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/)" still gives following error:

> OrderItem is not valid target type for the orderedItem property.

I am sharing a screenshot of related code, and its errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1eyb.png

```
<table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <link itemprop="orderStatus" href="http://schema.org/OrderProcessing" />
      <span itemprop="merchant" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="XYZ.com"/>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span itemprop="orderDate">August 10, 2016</span>
      <span itemprop="orderNumber">ABC12345</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Recipient</span>
      <span style="color:#333333;display:block;font-style:normal">
      Mr. <span itemprop="customer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name"> Nilesh S Ajwelkar</span></span><br/>
      kfjfjkfdkj abc
      <br/>lkjdfjkdfkj def<br/>
      jkfdjkdfjk ghi,
      AL
      63288<br/>
      USA
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
     <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD"/>
     <meta itemprop="price" content="539.00"/>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span itemprop="acceptedOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <meta  itemprop="name" content="ABCDEF prod"/>
        </span>
        <meta  itemprop="price" content="45.24"/>
        <meta  itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD"/>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr itemprop="orderedItem" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OrderItem">
    <td width="80" style="vertical-align:top;padding-left: 2px;" >
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img itemprop="image" src="http://image_link.com/1.jpg" alt="up sale image" height="80" width="80"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span itemprop="acceptedOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
              <span itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                <span  itemprop="name">NOT Girl with a Pearl Earring</span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </td>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span style="display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;">ITEM NUMBER</span>
            <span style="display:inline-block;padding-left:5px;color:#000000;" itemprop="orderItemNumber">17760</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td itemprop="orderQuantity">
            1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: block;color: #000000;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:12px;">
          <td>
            <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
              <span itemprop="price" content="32.85"/><span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
            </span>
            $32.85
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <link itemprop="orderItemStatus" href="http://schema.org/OrderProcessing"/>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <span itemprop="orderDelivery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ParcelDelivery">
              <span>Anticipated Arrival
                <span>Aug. 15 - Aug. 18</span>
              </span>
              <span itemprop="trackingNumber" content=""/>
              <span itemprop="trackingUrl" content=""/>
              <span itemprop="expectedArrivalUntil" content="2016-18-08"/>
              <span itemprop="expectedArrivalFrom" content="2016-15-08" />
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Nilesh Ajwelker, try using *itemOffered* and parent type *Offer*.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```html
<div itemprop="acceptedOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Samsung Chromebook"/>
      <meta itemprop="sku" content="B009LL9VDG"/>
      <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-XE303C12-A01US-Chromebook-Wi-Fi-11-6-Inch/dp/B009LL9VDG/"/>
      <link itemprop="image" href="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81H-DO3qX0L._SX522_.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Digging around the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order#order_with_billing_details), it looks like *orderedItem* is not supported.

As stated in the link below, "A few of the schema structures used by Gmail differ from the schema.org standard vocabulary."

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/schema-org-proposals